# Best method to total options sent to mySQL query through AJAX

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ajax

I have table, `charges`, that has fields, `id, name, price`. They are to hold extra charges like for a hotel stay (bottle of wine, PPV, bed of roses, etc) [anything extra to the price of the room] and I would like to display these as checkbox options to the user.

Now, I need to get those selected, know which where selected, and add that to the total. I am having trouble with the best way to do this. I am doing this using AJAX. I know how to send the checkboxes to the PHP file, it's once there that I am stuck.

Do I put all the checked into an array and all the names from the query into an array and compare the two, adding to the total when they match? It seems like there could be an easier way to accomplish this.

```
 //get extras
$query = 'SELECT name, price FROM charges'
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
```

Comment: yes. get the list of extras, show them as a checkbox, something like `<input type="options[]" value="$name" />$name - \${$price}`. then when the form is submitted, `$_POST['options']` will be an array of whatever the customer selected. You use those returned $name values to look up their price in the database again (do NOT round-trip price values through client-side), and off you go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the price on the fly, when the user checks the checkbox. For example,

```
<input class='check' type='checkbox' value='5' /> Food
<input class='check' type='checkbox' value='10' /> Drink
<input type='text' readonly id='total' name='total'>
```

Then use jQuery to add the values when checked.

```
 var vals = 0;
 $('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){
     if($(this).is(':checked')){
         vals += parseInt($(this).val());
     }else{
         vals -= parseInt($(this).val())
     }
     $('#total').val(vals);
 });
```

You have your total price, now you can go on with the form submit.

This is the case if you don't need all of your prices. But if you modify it just a little bit, you can use it to meet your need. Hope this helps.